# ASP Net Core and Integrated Windows Authentification

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, authentication, impersonation

consider following scenario:

- Users log in into their Windows computer using their credentials, which authentificates them to AD.
- ServiceX - an existing  API, which can be accessed only trough Integration Windows Auth.

Now is it possible add new web application service **NewService** which would consist of:

- **NewService-backend** (ASP Net Core - can be self-hosted or can be hosted behind IIS, within same domain as ServiceX)
- **NewService-frontend** (React)

in a way that following scenario would be possible:

1. User *Alice* logs into their Windows account
2. opens browser and navigates to url of **NewService**
3. the **NewService** app gets current users windows credentials, so the user does not need to input credentials again and can immediately start working as *Alice* in new app.
4. **Important** ...and the **NewService-backend** (not frontend) can call the **ServiceX** impersonating *Alice*

Is *4.* possible? I am not sure how the windows credentials are transmitted between browser and the app and if the they can be used by the **NewService-backend** to impersonate the user.

=============

**Clarification:**
We are mostly interested in solution how to call another service(s) in the name of domain user who called the first service.

1. User (*Alice*) makes request (from React app in browser) to **NewService-backend** using Windows Authentication.
2. **NewService-backend** makes request to **ServiceX** in the name of *Alice*.
3. **NewService-backend** is on different machine than **ServiceX**.

**What I am not sure about:**

- Can React app (in browser) pass the Windows user identity (?*SID*?) to **NewService-backend** and how?
- If so, can then the **NewService-backend** pass *Alice's* identity to **ServiceX** in order to **ServiceX** think that *Alice* is calling? How?

Comment: You're describing the default behavior since 2002, except the service *never* gets the user's credentials. It doesn't need them. As long as the web site is hosted on IIS, you can specify Windows Authentication on the web site itself. Even if it's not, as long as IIS is used as a reverse proxy it can take care of authentication

Comment: Are you asking about impersonation instead of authentication perhaps? Executing code on the server using the client credentials? Most of the time there's no reason to use the end user's credentials. You can easily check who the logged in user is

Comment: More probable is the following OpenID Connect scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#protocol-diagram-access-token-acquisition

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but how the **ServiceX** (whis is accesbile only trough Windows Authnetification) knows that it can fullfil request of the **NewService-backend**... or am I missing something?